# Connection types and its differences in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, connection, azure-logic-apps

There are basically three types of connection available in Azure Logic app

1- Api Connection

2- Service Provider connection

3- Function connection

can someone please share the difference between these there?.

like what are the advantage and disadvantage of using it ?

which one is best to use among these three ?

any specific difference between Api Connection Vs Service provider connection ?

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide an example of where you’ve had to apply each one?

Answer (score 0):

Below connection types are available in standard logic apps.

1. Api Connection: If you are trying to create a connection with Azure connector
2. Service Provider Connection: If you are creating a connection with Builtin Connector.
3. Function Connection: If you are creating a connection with Azure functions.

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/compare-built-in-azure-connectors) for more information about when to consider the built-in connector or Azure connector.